# Use USB unique ID as key license

Tags: linux, usb

I developed an application which will test I/O ports of the company's product which runs with **embedded linux**. But now we want to execute it from a specific USB, so it could be copied into another USB but shouldn't run.
This is my first approach to something like licensed software, I know there are **dongles** used as **license key**, but I'm not sure if it is possible to save my application on them.

My question is: is there any unique identifier for USBs that could be read from Linux, introduce that argument to the application and within the program tell if the USB is valid or not?

I used the `lsusb` command to get the USB information but couldn't tell if any value is truly unique to the device.
Doing my research, I found several sources that say that manufacturers don't give a unique ID to every USB device.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Is it an open source application?

Comment: Compile your program to VHDL so it would be harder to copy.
TLDR:"make hardware"/"use FPGA"

Comment: If there's a significant market for your product, someone will crack whatever protection method you use and upload a torrent.   If there isn't a significant market, the cost of implementing copy protection is probably far greater than what it might save.  In both cases, copy protection will greatly annoy (to put it politely) legitimate users who want to use what they have bought in ways you haven't thought of and/or who want to continue using them long after you've gone out of business (and can no longer supply backup/replacement USB keys). This will cost you sales & customers.

Comment: @cas how would a torrent help if they use a licence dongle? ad_valle, why don't you simply use a license server and make your program "phone home" to validate its license key which can easily be set to be specific to the client's hardware?

Comment: if it's cracked, the cracked version can be distributed. via torrent or whatever.   phone home "solutions" can be cracked too.

Comment: Hardware based copy protection doesn't work very well in general.  You might want to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's such an ID, and it's *pretty* unique. But the chief problems are that it's not cryptographically safe, and you can't rely on the OS to be truthful.

Comment: right now I am using lsusb on our linux version which returns the serial id (SerialNumber when using dmesg on Ubuntu) and yeah pretty easy to get it, so I couldn't trust on it.

Comment: Being easy to *get* isn’t a problem; the problem is that it’s easy to *fake*.